# How to logout firebase auth when app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Android is closed (swipe to close) or killed.
Firebase still is active.
How to sign out when the app is closed.

Comment: You're hoping the user has to sign in again each time to app is closed and re-opened? That's so I understand you clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logins are persistent and will be retained until you call the signOut API, or the user clears the app data somehow (maybe by uninstalling the app).  You can't force a logout when the app process dies.  You can instead detect this case on your own and call the signOut API as needed.

Comment: You can't call the API on the onDestory() activity lifecycle?

Comment: @Zamar onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called by Android.  You will have to detect on the next launch if the user should have been signed out, but whatever logic you decide.